# Adjust number of data for each row in the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I'm new in r and currently trying to adjust the number of data in each row in my data frame. I need this data as input in the dynamic global vegetation model: Fortran-based.

Here is my data:
[population data: 1 column x 22465 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K0Jn.png)

[download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HYS3dy89uBKj3u7czwiStQzHmPuznNGZ/view?usp=sharing)

My data has 1 column and 22,465 rows, 1 column contains 24 datas but I want each column to have 8 datas only, and the next 9-...n, written in the next row, and so on.

I need to reorder my data to be like this:
[land data: 1 column x 64799 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFctR.png)

[download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NER2DzHNyfUvv2RwLjqHrfDWqqZvSE2T/view?usp=sharing)

This problem was solved by @TarJae suggestion. Thanks.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
separate_rows(X1) %>% 
group_by(group_id =as.integer(gl(n(),8,n()))) %>% 
mutate(X1 = toString(X1)) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
select(-group_id)%>% 
as.data.frame

write.table(df1,"test.txt",col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with `dyplr` and `tidyr`:

1. Separate rows by comma
2. group rows of n = 8
3. use `toString` same as paste ...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(X1) %>% 
  group_by(group_id =as.integer(gl(n(),8,n()))) %>% 
  mutate(X1 = toString(X1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group_id)
```

```
  X1                    
   <chr>                 
 1 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 2 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 3 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 4 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 5 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 6 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 7 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 8 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
 9 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
10 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
# ... with 359,726 more rows
```

Comment: Hi @TarJae
Thank you very much, it works well!

I already exported the result in .txt format, but there are several empty data: before, between, and after the comma: ex. line 25,49,193 ..etc > (I uploaded the exported file in the questions) - I already searched the information but couldn't find it yet.

Do you have any further suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: @Kazuma. Please read this first  <https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask> then open a new question with the second problem.

Comment: oh okay, I'll open a new question in the second problem. Thanks a lot!